# Angular undefined value of @input variable

Tags: api, angular10

I'm new to Angular and I have some issues , hope you'll help me.
so I'm trying to share a value of a variable from a ProjectComponent to an AcceuilComponent , the value of this variable is displaying correctly into my acceuil.component.html but when I try to use it into my acceuil.component.ts it's undefined !

`project.component.html  (the parent component)`

```
 <app-header-in></app-header-in>

<ng-sidebar-container>

    <ng-sidebar [opened]="opened">
        <p> Sidebar </p>
        <button (click)="Sidebar()">
            Close Sidebar
        </button>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="hh"
            *ngFor="let project of projects"
            [class.selected]="project === selectedProject"
            (click)="onSelect(project)">
            {{project.nomprojet}}</li>
        </ul>
    </ng-sidebar>

    <div ng-sidebar-content >
    <br><br><br><br>
        <button (click)="Sidebar()">
            Open Sidebar
        </button>
        
        <app-acceuil [message]="idProject"></app-acceuil>
      
     </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

`project.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import {ProjectService} from '../project.service';
import {PartService} from '../part.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  opened=true;
  projects:any;
  idProject;
  selectedProject;
 
  constructor(private projectService:ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe((result)=>{console.log("result",result) 
    this.projects=result})
  }
  Sidebar(){
    this.opened=!this.opened;
  }
  onSelect(pro): void {
      this.idProject = pro.id;
  }


}
```

`acceuil.component.html  (my child component)`

```
    <p>{{message}}</p>
<ul >
    <li class="hh"
        *ngFor="let part of parts">
        {{part.nomparti}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

`acceuil.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import {PartService} from '../part.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-acceuil',
  templateUrl: './acceuil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./acceuil.component.css']
})


export class AcceuilComponent implements OnInit {

    
    @Input() message;
    parts:any;

    constructor(private partService:PartService) {
        
     }

    ngOnInit(): void{
        
        console.log("id",this.message);
        this.partService.getPartsFromIdProject(this.message).subscribe((result)=>{console.log("result",result) 
        this.parts=result})
    } 

    ngOnChanges() {
        if(this.message) {
        console.log(this.message)
    }
}

}
```

I'm using the message to call a service and displaying data .
in the acceuil.component.html `<p>{{message}}</p>` is displaying correctly but `console.log("id",this.message);` in acceuil.component.ts displays undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As message is an input property, you need to get its value in ngOnchanges life cycle.

First time, when it is in ngOnChanges, input value will be undefined. So for the safe side, better to add a check for **not undefiled** condition like below

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.message) {
    // Should be defined now
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```